# Convergence of a semiparametric estimator - a doubt

Tags: self-study, convergence, semiparametric

Suppose we have a parametric continuous function of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with d-dimensional parameter $\theta$
$$g(x;\theta)$$
we also have have an n-dimensional sample if i.i.d. observations of X.
With this sample we compute:

1. a "generic" statistic $\hat{\theta}_{n}$ (not necessarily an MLE) convergent in probability to a finite value that I plug in place of $\theta$;
2. a kernel density function $\hat{f}_{n,h}(x)$ with smoothing parameter h.

Suppose we want to compute an estimate of the expectation of $g$ as the following Integral $I(\hat{\theta}_{n},\hat{f}_{n,h})$

$$I(\hat{\theta}_{n},\hat{f}_{n,h}):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x;\hat{\theta}_{n})\hat{f}_{n,h}(x)dx$$

My question is:

Am I allowed to state that for the continuous mapping theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem  the integral $I(\hat{\theta}_{n},\hat{f}_{n,h})$ converges in probability?

Am I allowed to study the convergence as a Statistical functional assuming the Hadamard differentiability of $I(,)$? How to do it in this case?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said how $h$ varies with $n$ or depends on the data. If $h$ is constant, then $\hat f_{n,h}$ will converge to something, but not to the true density of $X$.  You also need to consider in what metric $\hat f_{n,h}$ converges in probability.

Suppose $h$ is chosen so that the MISE of $\hat f_{n,h}$ converges to zero in probability, so $\hat f_{n,h}$ converges to the true $f_0$ in probability in the $L_2$ norm.

The question is then whether  function $(\hat\theta, \hat f_{n,h})\mapsto I(\hat\theta, \hat f_{n,h})$ is continuous as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^d\times L_2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  If it is, you can use the continuous mapping theorem to argue
$$I(\hat\theta, \hat f_{n,h})\stackrel{p}{\to} I(\theta_0, f_0)$$

How nice does $g$ have to be for this to work? It would be enough for $g(x;\theta)$ to be bounded as a function of $x$ and Lipschitz as a function of $\theta$, since then both $g(x)(\hat f-f)(x)$ and $(g-\hat g)(x)f(x)$ would converge to zero pointwise.  You could certainly impose weaker conditions, but *some* conditions are necessary.

You need more conditions to look at the limiting distribution of $\hat I$, because this will be scaled up by some function of $n$. It's not going to be entirely straightforward, because $\hat\theta$ and $\hat f_{n,h}$ converge at different rates -- while $I$ might well be a Hadamard differentiable function of the empirical distribution, $\hat f$ typically won't be.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Lumley.

Answer (score 0):

@thomas-lumley I think that the Generalized Slutsky Theorem ([Eugene Demidenko. Mixed models: theory and applications with R. John Wiley & Sons, 2013](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uSmRAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Mixed%20Models:%20Theory%20and%20Applications%20with%20R%202nd%20Edition&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAqeOYo5jqAhVJyaQKHYUGBXMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=Mixed%20Models%3A%20Theory%20and%20Applications%20with%20R%202nd%20Edition&f=false) page 662-663 - Theorem 48) gives general conditions which are also suitable for a wide range of stochastic functionals $q_{n}(\hat{\theta}_{n})$ where  $\left\lbrace q_{n}\right\rbrace$ is a sequence of continuous stochastic functions while $\hat{\theta}_{n}$ is a consistent estimator.
In the case exposed above $q_{n}(\hat{\theta}_{n})$ would denote the integral $I(\hat{\theta}_{n},\hat{f}_{n,h_{n}})$.

The Theorem states that under the conditions:

1. $\mathbb{E}\left(\left\|{\boldsymbol {\dfrac{\partial q_{n}(\theta_{*})}{\theta}}}\right\|^{2} \right)\leq A $ for all $\left\|{\boldsymbol {\theta-\theta_{*}}}\right\|\leq \varepsilon$ uniformly over $n$
2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\left\|{\boldsymbol {\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta_{o}}}\right\|^{2}\right)=0$

where:

- $\varepsilon>0$
- $q_{n}(\theta)$ has first derivative
- $A=A(\varepsilon,\theta_{*})$ is a constant
- $plim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\hat{\theta}_{n}=\theta_{o}$

then

$$plim_{n\rightarrow \infty}q_{n}(\hat{\theta}_{n})=q(\theta_{o})$$

Comment: Yes, that's one set of generic conditions. My point was that stronger conditions on $g$ or $\hat\theta$ will allow you weaker conditions on $f$ and vice versa.  For example, if you know $\hat\theta$ is $\sqrt{n}$-consistent  (which it typically will be) you can weaken condition 1. And you didn't say in the question whether $g$ was differentiable wrt $\theta$, which is basically needed for condition 1.

Comment: Dear prof. @thomas-lumley , yes, I got what you mean. I think It is worth to consider both approaches whenever necessary. Thank you again!!!